Flutter - ObjectBox - All data removed
I'm facing an issue when using ObjectBox with flutter.
When I'm releasing a new version of the app (manually for now), all data are being deleted.
I ran the below command
flutter build ios --release; flutter install

My objectBox is initialized
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:appName/objectbox.g.dart';

class ObjectBox {
  /// The Store of this app.
  late final Store store;

  ObjectBox._create(this.store) {
    // Add any additional setup code, e.g. build queries.
  }

  /// Create an instance of ObjectBox to use throughout the app.
  static Future<ObjectBox> create() async {
    final docsDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    // Future<Store> openStore() {...} is defined in the generated objectbox.g.dart
    final store = await openStore(directory: p.join(docsDir.path, "appName"));
    return ObjectBox._create(store);
  }
}

final objectBoxProvider =
    Provider<ObjectBox>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());

/// ... Into main

var o = await ObjectBox.create();
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      overrides: [objectBoxProvider.overrideWithValue(o)],
      child: App(),
    ),
  );


Any ideas ?
Thanks
Tried both getApplicationSupportDirectory and getApplicationDocumentsDirectory to no avail.
